# ios 6 Storyboards and Custom Layouts based on orientation

Tags: iphone, ipad, layout, ios6, storyboard

Been trying to find some tips on suggested approach for this and not having much luck.

All I'm looking for is to know what is the best approach to handle custom layouts for `portrait/landscape` modes.

I've seen some posts say in the storyboard add 2 views to the same `ViewController` and `show/hide` based on orientation change while some people suggest to use a totally separate `ViewController` for each orientation.

Which of this is the preferred method. I'm just starting my application, So I'd rather go for the widely accepted method than have to deal with complications later on.

Apple documentation still keeps talking about nib files and not storyboards in this aspect, so not being of much help.

My main focus is performance (I'm fine with having to code stuff instead of depend on the graphical interface for it). separate ViewControllers seem to keep the code in a clean way however if that involves populating views / clearing them every time orientation changes, seems kind of expensive(not sure if it is relevant).

Also if each scene in the application has 2 layouts then managing them I'm not sure how much of a pain it's going to be when the application grows big.

Please point me in a suitable approach for my case,

am not concerned about backwards compatibility. Just worried about the latest `Xcode` and `ios6` if it matters for the decision

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this really depends on the level of customization of the UI in portrait vs landscape. A large number of implementations I have done can be handled by either autoresizing/autolayout when switching orientation, or simply moving the elements yourself when the UI is rotated and the callbacks are fired. Moving the elements around should not be an expensive operation at all as it is a very common occurrence (again this depends on the complexity of your UI though).

Comment: Moving the elements I take it cannot work with auto layout/ auto resizing and my only concern is if I move elements manually on orientation change to a fixed anchor point and size wouldn't it affect localizations? The difference in my layouts aren't of the order of changing item types like a image in portrait becomming graph in landscape. Changes are mainly just in positions like tab bar which is horizontal in portrait becomming vertical in landscape and so on

Comment: You should be able to work with some autosizing + specific placement of the start X,Y coordinates (or off a center). Also investigate sizeToFit if localization-sizing is an issue.